# Create a multidimensional PHP array with a checkpoint for same key

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-6

I am trying to create a multidimensional array in PHP using a foreach loop. I have a days table for storing the days and a hours table for storing open & close time and reference id for the day. Every day has two shifts. Here is the code that I have tried so far:

```
foreach ($days as $value) {
            foreach ($value->hours as $key=>$val) {
                if (array_key_exists($value->name, $storeSchedule)) {
                    $storeSchedule[$value->name][] = array($val->opening_time => $val->closing_time);
                }else{
                    $storeSchedule[$value->name][] = array($val->opening_time => $val->closing_time);
                }
            }
        }
```

Current Output:

```
Array
(
    [Mon] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [11:00:00] => 02:00:00
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [16:00:00] => 22:00:00
                )
        )
    [Tue] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [11:00:00] => 02:00:00
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [16:00:00] => 22:00:00
                )
        )
    [Wed] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [11:00:00] => 02:00:00
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [16:00:00] => 22:00:00
                )
        )
    [Thur] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [11:00:00] => 02:00:00
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [16:00:00] => 22:00:00
                )
        )
    [Fri] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [11:00:00] => 02:00:00
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [16:00:00] => 22:00:00
                )
        )
    [Sat] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [11:30:00] => 15:30:00
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [16:00:00] => 21:00:00
                )
        )
    [Sun] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [11:30:00] => 15:30:00
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [16:00:00] => 21:00:00
                )
        )
)
```

Expected Output:

```
Array
(
    [Sun] => Array
        (
            [11:30 AM] => 03:30 PM
            [04:00 PM] => 09:00 PM
        )
    [Mon] => Array
        (
            [11:00 AM] => 2:00 PM
            [04:00 PM] => 10:00 PM
        )
    [Tue] => Array
        (
            [11:00 AM] => 2:00 PM
            [04:00 PM] => 10:00 PM
        )
    [Wed] => Array
        (
            [11:00 AM] => 2:00 PM
            [04:00 PM] => 10:00 PM
        )
    [Thu] => Array
        (
            [11:00 AM] => 2:00 PM
            [04:00 PM] => 10:00 PM
        )
    [Fri] => Array
        (
            [11:00 AM] => 2:00 PM
            [04:00 PM] => 10:00 PM
        )
    [Sat] => Array
        (
            [11:30 AM] => 03:30 PM
            [04:00 PM] => 09:00 PM
        )
)
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the issue. Please find the corrected foreach loop below:

```
foreach ($days as $value) {
            foreach ($value->hours as $key=>$val) {
                if (array_key_exists($value->name, $storeSchedule)) {
                    foreach ($storeSchedule[$value->name] as $k => $v) {
                        $ee=array($k => $v, $val->opening_time => $val->closing_time);
                    }
                    unset($storeSchedule[$value->name]);
                    $storeSchedule[$value->name] = $ee;
                }else{
                    $storeSchedule[$value->name] = array($val->opening_time => $val->closing_time);
                }
            }
        }
```